# jquery code optimization for a checked or not checked input

Tags: jquery, optimization, checkbox, input, html-table

I have this code which take all checks of my table and set them checked,
 I'm trying to rewrite it in a small way, but I don't imagine another, is there such a way?

```
$('[name=select_todos]').bind('click', function () {
    if ($('[name=select_todos]').is(':checked')) {
        $('#dataTableListModal tbody tr').each(function () {
            $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        });
    } else {
        $('#dataTableListModal tbody tr').each(function () {
            $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
});
```

The final idea is to make it shorter in the amount of code I use.

Comment: yeah, that could be made quite a bit shorter. there's no need for .each in this case, and no reason to re-select the clicked element. the if statement can also be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `$(':checkbox')`, thinking that it only applies to the `#dataTableListModal`, but instead it matches all checkboxes.

Below, it's using *selector context*. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

This is short enough?

```
$('[name=select_todos]').on('click', function () {
    $(':checkbox', '#dataTableListModal').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

#### FYI

If you are puzzled by the lack of `.each(…)`: all methods like `.css()`, `.prop()`, `.addClass()`, `.attr()`, etc. *automatically* work on collections (e.g. when a `.selector` matches more than 1 element). So `.each` is redundant in those cases.

You use `each` when you want to pass a custom function, but since your `each( callback )` is only calling standard jQuery methods, there is no need for it in your case.

#### FYI 2

All `.selectors` always return a collection (similar to an Array), even if there is only 1 element in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

$(':checkbox').prop('checked', false); or $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true)  in loop?
If your table each tr contains checkbox then you can easily do in this way

```
$('[name=select_todos]').bind('click', function () {
    var table_rows = $('#dataTableListModal tbody tr'),
        is_todo_checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    table_rows.each(funtion(ind, tr){
           $(tr).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', is_todo_checked);
        });
});
```

I hope it will short your code also.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$('[name=select_todos]').on('change', function () {
    $('#dataTableListModal tbody tr').find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",$(this).prop("checked"))  
});
```